# A permutation statistic and determinantal identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, permutations

I'm trying to read this paper, *Total positivity, Grassmannians and networks* by Postnikov (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609764) and I'm stuck on Lemma 5.1, which is essentially an identity about maximal minors of a matrix.

*Lemma 5.1.* Let $I$ and $J$ be two $k$-element subsets in $[n]$, $K = I\setminus J$ and $L = J \setminus I$. Also let $r = |K| = |L|$. Then the following identity holds for the Plücker coordinates in $Gr_{kn}$
$$\Delta_J \cdot \Delta_I^{r-1} = \sum_{\pi: K \to L}(-1)^{\operatorname{xing}(\pi)}\prod_{i\in K}\Delta_{(I\setminus\{i\})\cup\{\pi(i)\}}.$$

Please see the paper for the relevant definitions. The crossing number is (I believe) not the usual one by his definition. I can't see why the following claims in the proof are true:

1. $\operatorname{xing}(\pi) = \binom{r}{2}-\operatorname{inv}(\pi)$
2. This identity, which he reduces the above to, is true:
   $$\det B = \sum_{\pi: K \to L}(-1)^{\binom{r}{2}-\operatorname{inv}(\pi)}\prod_{i \in [r]}(-1)^{r-j}b_{i,\pi(i)}.$$ I'm happy that $$(-1)^{\binom{r}{2}-\operatorname{inv}(\pi)}\prod_{i \in [r]}(-1)^{r-\pi(i)}b_{i,\pi(i)} = (-1)^{\binom{r}{2}-\operatorname{inv}(\pi) + \binom{r}{2}}\prod_{i \in [r]}b_{i,\pi(i)} = (-1)^{-\operatorname{inv}(\pi)}b_{i,\pi(i)}.$$ This seems really close to the definition of the determinant, but off by a minus sign. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere.

Thank you!

Comment: On the second question: $\left(-1\right)^{-a} = \left(-1\right)^a$.

Comment: As for the first question, keep in mind that Postnikov has WLOG assumed that $I $ and $J $ are rather special subsets.

Comment: Incidentally, you seem to be reading an outdated version of Postnikov's preprint. See https://math.mit.edu/~apost/papers/tpgrass.pdf for a newer one.

Comment: Oh oh oh oh. Ok that makes so much more sense now. Thank you!!